# Create docker programatically with NodeJs for user? And Connect with domain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, express, docker-compose

I am creating a CRM for multiple types like BPO,IT,Sales,Retail..etc. Is this possible to create separate docker container for every user when they register and connect it with subdomain. Example.

1.You registered on [www.abcrm.com](http://www.abcrm.com)

2.You get a link with you name :  david.abcrm.com

3.That dashboard will be served inside docker container which is linked to [www.david.abcrm.com](http://www.david.abcrm.com)

If anyone knows it please help. Thank You ❤️

Comment: It's theoretically possible, but it sounds like a huge management and scaling problem to me.  Of particular note, remember that you can't create a container or otherwise manipulate containers without having unrestricted root-level access over the entire host, so there are significant security concerns here; also that each container will be running its own copy of your application, which can dramatically increase your memory requirements with only a couple of concurrent users.

Comment: Ok is there any way to do the same without container ? Is there any way to give custom subdomains to user for dashboard. Like in website suppose it will be like www.abcrm.com/dashboard example. User will get domain that will point to this and so on

Comment: Like how atlassian gives us custom domain. Is it possible?